# Как перевести 3d скан с расширением .obj в .fbx для изменения в cad программах?

Tags: 3d, autocad, сканирование

Купил 3д сканер, появилась задача переводить отсканированный объект в формат, который можно открыть в t-flex cad (.fbx, например). Кто-нибудь знает подходящую программу?

Сканер Sense 3d от 3dsystems
http://www.3dsystems.com/shop/sense/order

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте экспортировать в VRML и импортировать его в t-flex. Поддержка заявлена и там и там.